# MatrixExp of a complex matrix of size about 10000 by 10000

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra

I want to apply `MatrixExp` of a numerical, complex matrix of size about 10000 by 10000, and I also need high precision as I need to multiply several such matrices. However, I run out of memory during the computation. Is there a way to exponentiate the matrix without running out of the memory? Any helpful suggestions will be useful.

My problem is that given a sparse matrix $A$ which does not have zeroes on diagonal as well. I need $e^{i\, A\, t}$, where $t$ is the time. One needs to keep the phase information of each entry.

Comment: Do you really need the entire matrix, or is your intent to multiply this matrix with a suitable vector later?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You should really state your problem and your ultimate goal by giving specific *Mathematica* code to reproduce the issue. If you tell us what you really want to achieve, it could be that you'll get a completely different answer that makes your large matrices unnecessary. As it is written, the question cannot be answered except by blind guessing, which is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: What type of numbers are in the matrix? Integers, machine precision reals or arbitrary precision numbers?

Comment: ...and, is the matrix sparse?

Comment: The problem has been updated. The matrix is sparse. However, I need to keep track of all phase informations as I have to use this complex matrix result to get a real result eventually.

Comment: You still haven't answered most of the above questions. And with respect to sparse matrices: did you use `SparseArray`? And how sparse is your sparse matrix?

Comment: ...if, for instance, you are in fact using the matrix exponential to solve a differential equation, then you fit the scenario I was referring to in my first comment, and you do **not** need the entire matrix; `MatrixExp[]`'s second argument will allow you to just compute the *action* of the matrix exponential.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis I do need the whole matrix for taking the whole trace later. It will not be multiplied by a vector at all. I am not solving PDEs or ODEs. I need all the phase information in order to obtain the ensemble average after the measurement operation. This matrix itself will evolve over the time and projection operator will be inserted each time during the measurement. Hence, I do need the whole matrix.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Using the sparsearray requires specification of values and positions of the variables. This is equivalent to computing the whole matrix. I need the whole matrix. I have to take ensemble average. It will not be multiplied to a vector eventually. Trace operation is more or less but I have to insert projection operator after exponentiation.

Comment: You can do all operations you like on sparse arrays, but the advantage is that memory use can be significant less than standard arrays (depending on sparsity of course).

Comment: If all you want is the trace, I'm pretty sure you don't need the entire matrix for it; the algorithms are not built-in, tho, and you may have to do some programming.

Comment: For finding the trace of a matrix, including a sparse matrix, there's the built-in function `Tr`. (I don't understand the comment, "the algorithms are not built-in."

Comment: @user45765 If all you need to do is exponentiate and take the trace, then you can use `Tr@Exp@Eigenvalues@A`. In fact, the eigenvalues of $e^A$ are the exponentials of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Inserting a projection is not very different from applying the matrix to (a set of) vectors. Since you have a time parameter `t`, I'm now guessing that your problem can be rewritten as a partial differential equation (where the large dimension just expresses a discretization of some continuous degree of freedom). But there's not enough information to go on.

Comment: @Jens I have to calculate the following quantity $S_n=Tr(\prod^{n}_{1}P_iOP'_i)$ where $P_i=Pe^{iAt_i}$ and $P'_i=e^{iAt_i}P$. I do not think you can write this trivially as some matrix ODE solutions as this is not some trivial time evolution with extra projection operator insertion. I do not have anyway to further to reduce $P$'s dimension.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Can you give me the link to the algorithm I need to do this calculation as I could not find a relevant one at the moment by google and $e^{iAt}$ is the sum of exponentials?

Comment: Can you use a matrix composition? If you have to calculate exp(X) for X given, decomposing X=AYB (Y: diagonal matrix) can make the calculations easier.